Can a particle have a mass greater than that of Higgs's boson's?
Up till now in our particle physics course, the most massive particle we've seen so far is Higgs's boson's. My question is, is there any restriction that doesn't allow particles to have greater mass? If there indeed is one and we suppose the existence of such particle, how could that affect our current understanding of QED theory?

this is not true "the most massive particle we've seen so far is Higgs's boson's. ". the top has a much higher  mass,  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html . about the higgs boson http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/higgs.html

I don't understand your last statement. The Higgs field belongs not to QED but to the Electro-Weak (Glashow-Weinberg-Salam) theory.

@JeanbaptisteRoux reference to a description of how the Higgs boson enters the story.

In view of the top quark mass, it is unclear what is asked.

The top quark is heavier.$\ \ \ \ $

There are no such restrictions. I'll try to give a brief outline of why that's the case. For a real scalar field $\chi$ (I'll restrict this discussion to one for simplicity, the main point can be understood in this situation), in a Lagrangian, a mass term is an object of the form
$$\frac{1}{2}m^2\chi^2$$
where $m$ is its be the mass. But consider now a theory with two scalars $\phi$ and $\chi$, coupled via the following interaction
$$\mathcal{L}\supset \frac{1}{2}y\phi\chi^2$$
Now, this does not look, at first, like a mass term, after all this a trilinear term in the fields. However, nature likes to be at the energy minima, and the notion of particle, roughly, is that they are excitations around this minimum we call the vacuum. And as such, maybe our field $\phi$ has a non-zero value in the vacuum, say $v$. In such a situation, if we want to retain the tools we use commonly, as well as the notion of particle for every field in our theory, then we need to reparametrize $\phi$ as follows
$$\phi(x)=v+h(x)$$
Now, $h$ is a new field representing "excitations" around this non-trivial vacuum, this is what the Higgs Boson is (except the $\phi$ is an SU(2) doublet instead of a real one component field, but the main point stands). Putting this back into the interaction, we find
$$\frac{1}{2}y\phi\chi^2=\frac{1}{2}yv\chi^2+\frac{1}{2}yh\chi^2$$
Now the first term above gives $\chi$ a mass of
$$m^2_\chi=yv$$
Notice here that this $y$ parameter is just a free parameter of the theory, often called a Yukawa coupling. Hence, the mass acquired can, in principle, be as large as you need. And in fact, there is a particle in the Standard Model with a Yukawa so big that the resulting mass is bigger than the Higgs', the top quark.
Obs: Obviously this is a much simplified toy model, in the Standard Model quarks are fermions not bosons and as such their associated field is spinorial. But I believe this is sufficient to get the point across.
